# How to create a git local server that uses git lfs

Tags: linux, git, server, local, git-lfs

A have a rasberry pi(Debian) with a local git server in it. I was able to push normal files to the repo but when I try to push big files it gives me this error.

> batch request: bash: git-lfs-authenticate: command not found: exit status 127

Im connection to the rasberry via ssh.
I have installed in both sides git lfs (maybe I did it wrong)

I was able to use git lfs to push into GitHub but not into my local server.
Do I have to create a different type of server of just with the git one should work;

Answer (score 3):

Git and Git LFS are two separate projects.  Git includes a server which can be used over the SSH protocol, but Git LFS does not.

There are two possible approaches for using Git LFS over SSH.  The older form uses a program called `git-lfs-authenticate`, which provides authentication for an HTTP server, and then the data is uploaded over HTTP or HTTPS.  If you're using Git LFS 3.0 or newer on the client side, it also supports a pure SSH protocol using the `git-lfs-transfer` program.  While Git LFS does not include that program, the reference implementation is written in Rust and can be built with `cargo install scutiger-lfs` (which can be adjusted to install where you'd like it to be located).  That program will need to be installed on the server side in the `PATH` for it to be available.

Comment: So if I have installed git LFS in my server y only have to use gut LFS transfer in the client?

Comment: If you've installed the `git-lfs-transfer` program from `scutiger-lfs` on the server, you can use the regular Git LFS client on the client, assuming you're using v3.0.0 or newer.